# Regex findall with logical or

Tags: python, regex

How can I do an 'or' in regex. I read that I need to simply put the various expressions into parenthesis, but the following findall doesn't work when I try to get any output after 'Total:' or 'Price for 1 night@'.

```
p = re.findall(r'(Total: (.*))(Price for 1 night: (.*))',s)
```

To give some more context:

```
prices1=[]

soup = bs(content, 'lxml')
s=soup.prettify()
p = re.findall(r'(Total: (.*))|(Price for 1 night: (.*))',s)
for x in p:
    if '£' in x:
        num=int(x.replace('£',''))
        prices1.append(num)
```

Source:

```
http://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-17CAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaFCIAQGYAS64AQTIAQTYAQHoAQH4AQs&sid=1a43e0952558ac0ad0061d5b6523a7bc&dcid=1&checkin_monthday=23;checkin_year_month=2016-1;checkout_monthday=24;checkout_year_month=2016-1;&city=-2601889&class_interval=1&csflt=%7B%7D&dtdisc=0&group_adults=7&group_children=0&highlighted_hotels=1192837&hlrd=0&hp_sbox=1&hyb_red=0&inac=0&label_click=undef&nflt=ht_id%3D201%3B&nha_red=0&no_rooms=1&redirected_from_city=0&redirected_from_landmark=0&redirected_from_region=0&review_score_group=empty&room1=A%2CA%2CA%2CA%2CA%2CA%2CA&sb_price_type=total&score_min=0&si=ai%2Cco%2Cci%2Cre%2Cdi&ss=London&ss_all=0&ssafas=1&ssb=empty&sshis=0&ssne=London&ssne_untouched=London&order=price_for_two
```

Example values:

```
<strong class="price scarcity_color sr_gs_rackrate_price
 anim_rack_rate  
" title="Price for 1 night £69">
<b>
<span class="sr_gs_rackrate_total">Total: </span>
£69
</b>
</strong>
<td class="totalPrice" colspan="3">
<div data-component="track" data-hash="OLNYSRfCbdWGffSRe" data-stage="1" data-track="view"></div>
Total: £145
</td>
```

Comment: Instead of the link you could have give us the value of `s`

Comment: The value is extremely long

Comment: Then maybe just the interesting part ?

Comment: Added additional info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should clean your input, removing every HTML tag with a replace and this regex `</?[^>]*>`.

Then you'll have something like `Total: £69 Total: £145`. As you don't want to match `£69 Total: £145` but the actual prices, you'll have to change `.` to `[^\s]` (match anything but whitespace).

Then you just need to add a `|` between your conditions:

```
Total: ([^\s]*)|Price for 1 night: ([^\s]*)
```

<kbd>[Live Demo (updated)](https://regex101.com/r/qQ2zP9/3)</kbd>

Comment: Definitely a step into the right direction but doesn't work with the demo text I added. Any suggestions are appreciated how I can just get the numbers

Comment: Really cool. I think with a replace that works, but is there a way to do two regex in one? For example with "night (.*)|Total(.*)" I could then add a second one just look for '£' with an and operator to just look for the number after the £?

Comment: @Nicolas [Let's continue to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101459/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-34962224-regex-findall-with-logical-or)